# Tcl 'file exists' misses generated files

Tags: tcl

While debugging a third-party Tcl script, I ran into a very strange behavior: when the script decompresses an existing file via gunzip, Tcl 'file exists' denies that the result file exists, even though it is visible via 'ls' from a shell and even via Tcl 'glob'.  I was able to replicate the behavior in this short(ish) script:

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh

proc assert {msg asserted} {
  if {!$asserted} {
    puts "Assertion failed: $msg"
    exit 1
  }
}

set script_path [info script]
set test_file [file join [file dirname $script_path] "test.tcl.gz"]
puts "The test file is '$test_file'"
assert "The test file does not exist" [file exists $test_file]

set this_dir [pwd]
set test_dir [file join $this_dir "test"]
if {![file exist $test_dir]} {
  file mkdir $test_dir
}
puts "The test directory is '$test_dir'"
assert "'$test_dir' does not exist or is not a directory" [file isdirectory $test_dir]

file copy $test_file $test_dir
set working_file [file join $test_dir [file tail $test_file]]
assert "Failed to to copy the test file to '$working_file'" [file exists $working_file]

exec gunzip $working_file
puts "After decompression, $test_dir contains:"
foreach file [glob -dir $test_dir *] {
  puts $file
}
set decompressed_file [file rootname $working_file]
assert "$decompressed_file does not exist" [file exists $decompressed_file]
```

The test file I'm using is just a gzipped copy of the script source.  It resides in the same directory as the script itself, as the script expects and checks.  Here's what I get when I run it (tcl 8.5 / CentOS 6.5):

```
bash-4.1$ ./test.tcl 
The test file is './test.tcl.gz'
The test directory is '/home/jbolling/tmp/test'
After decompression, /home/jbolling/tmp/test contains:
/home/jbolling/tmp/test/test.tcl
Assertion failed: /home/jbolling/tmp/test/test.tcl does not exist
```

Can anyone explain this behavior?  Is there a way to persuade 'file exists' to recognize the decompressed file?

Comment: I'm not getting an assertion failed error when running your script.  Can you do a `ls -ld . test test/test.tcl`.

Comment: I am not see the assertion failure either. My environment: Mac OS X 10.9.x, Tcl 8.5.9.

Comment: The `file exists` command maps pretty much directly to the `access()` system call with the `F_OK` flag on all Unixes, including OSX; Windows is more complex because of the difference in file locking models. What platform are you on?

Comment: @Brad Lanam: 'ls' shows the file existing, just as 'glob' does.  The working directory (. = /home/jbolling/tmp) has permissions 0750, subdirectory 'test' has permissions 0755, and test/test.tcl has permissions 0644.

Comment: @Donal Fellows: this is CentOS 6.5 (Linux).

Comment: In light of the reports that the script does not report an assertion failure for some, I investigated a little further.  I found that commenting out line 25, the assertion about `[file exists $working_file]`, resulted in the final assertion succeeding.  Could there be some kind of caching going on here -- maybe `file exists` maintaining an internal cache of the directory contents -- that that is going stale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After learning from others' comments that the original script worked for them, discovering some variants that also worked for me, and poking around some in the Tcl source code, I have come to a conclusion: having once used `file exists` on an object, it is unsafe to use it again on that object or on one derived from it via `file rootname` if the contents of the directory may have changed between the calls (which cannot often be ruled out).

I haven't traced down where it's happening in the source, but my Tcl interpreter is clearly caching the results of a directory listing somewhere, for not only does it not recognize the creation of the decompressed file, it also does not recognize the *removal* of the original (that gunzip also performs).  On the other hand, if I perform the `file exists` test using a literal string path or using a Tcl object that is sufficiently separated from any previously passed to `file exists`, then the result is as expected.  It also works if I force a conversion to a string by, for example, replacing

```
assert "$decompressed_file does not exist" [file exists $decompressed_file]
```

with

```
assert "$decompressed_file does not exist" [file exists [string trim $decompressed_file]]
```

Evidently the caching behavior is implementation-specific; my implementation is Tcl 8.5.7 of CentOS 6.5, but I suppose the behavior is probably general at least to the Unix implementation of Tcl 8.5.7 (which is different from the macosx implementation, even though OS X is Unix).  It may also be that gunzip is doing something unusual that contributes to the problem, for I was unable to duplicate it by `exec`ing a simple mv command.

Anyway, even though I haven't fully characterized the problem, I think I now understand it well enough to be confident about working around the issue.  Thanks to those who commented -- you guided me in a fruitful direction.

Answer (score 0):

The manual for [file exists](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/file.htm#M15) states that the command

> Returns 1 if file name exists and the current user has search
>   privileges for the directories leading to it, 0 otherwise.

Clearly the file exists, so I suspect that the user you're running the script as doesn't have permission to see it. I must confess I'm not quite sure what "search privileges for the directories leading to it" means.

I suggest trying it again with the file located in a publically accessible directory.

Comment: "Search privileges" for `/a/b/c/d/file.txt` means you have to be able to cd into `/a`, `/a/b`, `/a/b/c` ... and so on, all the way to `/a/b/c/d`

Comment: The script *creates* the target file, by first copying a gzipped version into the target directory and then decompressing it.  It is running as me, and I certainly have search privileges for all directories in the path to it (a subdirectory of my home directory), which I can verify outside the script.

Comment: Moreover, the script successfully uses `file exists` to test the existence of the .gz in the target directory before decompressing, so the problem cannot be explained by search lack of privileges on that directory.

Comment: Very strange. I wonder is it an artefact of you running it as a shell script. Could you open a TCL shell, and paste the code directly in, and see if that is any different?

Comment: I opened an interactive tclsh, and pasted my original script (above) into it.  It gave me the same 'glob' result and the same inconsistent assertion failure.  It was an interesting thought, but no dice.

Comment: Ok, I know you're on Linux, so this probably won't make a difference, but you should really be using "file nativename" with exec calls. http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/file.htm#M24 It wouldn't hurt either to try "file normalize" too in case something weird is going with symbolic links etc

Answer (score 0):

Minor issue, but looks like a possible typo here...

```
if {![file exist $test_dir]} {
```

should be:

```
if {![file exists $test_dir]} {
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  (1) You are correct that there is a typo in the posted source, but it does not actually affect the behavior of the script in any way (oddly).  The script runs exactly as originally posted, and it runs also with the typo corrected, yielding exactly the same filesystem changes and printed output either way. (2) This would be far more appropriate as a comment on the original question than as an answer, as it does not, in fact, answer the question.